# Does the rate of effusion remain constant throughout the effusion?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Suppose a gas is effusing from a container through a small orifice at constant temperature and pressure. Does the rate of effusion (no of moles of gas effused per unit time) remain constant throughout the effusion or does it decrease with time as the no. of moles of the gas decrease in the container?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! What have you attempted to do with regards to the answer to this question? We need to make sure we aren't doing your homework for you.

Comment: It depends how you read the question. If p and T are constant inside the vessel then 'no' as the gas effuses more must be added to keep pressure constant, if pressure is constant outside then 'yes' as sooner or later there is no gas left to effuse :)

Comment: I am actually a student of Grade 12 preparing for a pre-medical entrance exam. So, I am clearing my doubts of chemistry here as I don't have any good chemistry teachers to whom I can ask these doubts.

Answer (score 1):

For a container with a constant initial amount of gas at constant T, the rate of effusion decreases with time, [since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effusion#Measures_of_flow_rate)

$$\phi_N = \frac{\Delta P A N_A}{\sqrt{2\pi MRT}}$$

where A is the aperture, $\Delta P$ the pressure drop at the exit of the container, M is the molar mass of the gas, and T is the temperature. You can also consult a physical chemistry textbook to verify the equation.

Assume the pressure outside the container is zero (for simplicity) and assume the gas obeys the ideal gas law. Then the equation can be rewritten as

$$\phi_N = \rho_N A N_A\sqrt{\frac{ RT}{2\pi M}}  \\= \kappa \rho_N $$

where $\rho_N$ is the molar density of the gas in the container, and $\kappa=A N_A\sqrt{\frac{ RT}{2\pi M}}$ is a constant for a given container, gas and temperature.

Now since $\rho_N$ decreases as gas is allowed to escape, then so does the flow rate.

Comment: What is M in the equation?

Comment: What exactly is delta P in the equation? Is it equal to Pressure inside the container - Pressure outside the container? Is it equal to partial pressure of the gas? What is it?

Comment: @RIPANBARUAH Please read my answer again: M is the molar mass of the gas and $\Delta P$ the difference in pressure between the inside and outside (the drop in pressure). But for the second equation I assume that the outside pressure is zero, so that $\Delta P = P$.

Comment: Suppose the outside pressure is zero. Then can we say that delta P = Pressure inside the container = Partial Pressure of the gas?

Comment: @RIPANBARUAH Yes, that sounds correct.

Comment: Suppose we have a container in which we have filled a gas with some partial pressure $P_{gas}$. Suppose we have fitted a piston inside the container which is exerting pressure inside the container. Suppose the pressure exerted by the piston inside the container or on the gas is $P_{piston}$. Then is it safe to say that $P_{gas} = P_{piston}$?

Comment: @RIPANBARUAH Unless you happen to cross the boiling point at the T of your gas, yes.